# check record exist in azure table inside azure logical app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have following json object in logical app

```
 {
      'eventSourceId': '1232',
       'eventType' : 'Email',
        'application' : 'ZENQ',
    }
```

I have one  azure table 'notification'. Now I want to  check whether data exist for  eventSourceId 1232  if it exist  I  need to update some columns if it does not exist ,the record needs to be created.
Now how do I write above condition in azure-logic app ?

[using Get Entities-Select Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnlUW.png)

I have used Get Entities-Select query with parameter but not sure how to check result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, I think your table has a column named "**eventSourceId**". So we do not need to write select sql, we can use "Filter Query" easily. Please refer to my logic app below:

[image]

The expression in "Condition" is:

```
length(body('Get_entities')?['value'])
```